# mysql value greater than percent of number of values

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I want to find name where the age is greater than n percent of all values in some year.
Here's the table:

```
mysql> select * from cust;
+------+------+------+
| name | age  | year |
+------+------+------+
| toni |   21 | 2016 |
| robi |   22 | 2016 |
| deni |   23 | 2016 |
| jeki |   24 | 2016 |
| yodi |   25 | 2016 |
| rino |   26 | 2016 |
| goli |   27 | 2016 |
| tobi |   28 | 2016 |
| lemi |   29 | 2016 |
| lora |   30 | 2016 |
| riko |   25 | 2017 |
| soni |   26 | 2017 |
| bino |   27 | 2017 |
| kola |   28 | 2017 |
| zoki |   29 | 2017 |
| mera |   30 | 2017 |
| noki |   31 | 2017 |
| peni |   32 | 2017 |
| vino |   33 | 2017 |
| heri |   34 | 2017 |
+------+------+------+
```

DDL:

```
create table tbl ( name varchar(10), age int, year  int);
insert into tbl values
('toni', 21, 2016 ),
('robi', 22, 2016 ),
('deni', 23, 2016 ),
('jeki', 24, 2016 ),
('yodi', 25, 2016 ),
('rino', 26, 2016 ),
('goli', 27, 2016 ),
('tobi', 28, 2016 ),
('lemi', 29, 2016 ),
('lora', 30, 2016 ),
('riko', 25, 2017 ),
('soni', 26, 2017 ),
('bino', 27, 2017 ),
('kola', 28, 2017 ),
('zoki', 29, 2017 ),
('mera', 30, 2017 ),
('noki', 31, 2017 ),
('peni', 32, 2017 ),
('vino', 33, 2017 ),
('heri', 34, 2017 );
```

I want to find name from year 2017 where the age is greater than 60% of all age in year 2016. I have done something like this

```
select name from cust where year=2017 and age>
    (SELECT age
    FROM    (
        SELECT cust.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
        FROM (select @counter:=0) AS initvar, cust where year=2016
        ORDER BY age DESC   
    ) AS X
    where counter <= (60/100 * @counter) 
    ORDER BY age DESC);
```

I know it's wrong but you know what I mean is comparing values between main query 
and subquery but I want that subquery is more than 1 row.
Is there a solution that was valid but kind a similar with above?

Edit: here's my desired output:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| soni |
| bino |
| kola |
| zoki |
| mera |
| noki |
| peni |
| vino |
| heri |
+------+
```

Comment: "where the age is greater than 60% of all age in year 2016." define?? Do you mean the age are summed altogether from year 2016 and taking 80% from that number

Comment: nope, just greater than 60% of number of all age in year 2016

Comment: @Yarp repeating the same will not make it clearer...

Comment: "just greater than 60% of number of all age in year 2016" You mean count the age records from year 2016 that number * 0.60.. And select the people with a higher age?..

Comment: What is 60% of all age in year 2016? Is it the same as a percentile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple query:

```
select name
from tbl t
where (select count(*) from tbl where year = 2016 and age <= t.age) /
      (select count(*) from tbl where year = 2016) >= 0.6 
  and year = 2017;
```

In the `where` clause you simply divide count of younger people in 2016 by all people in 2016, which gives you the percentage (`0.0` to `1.0`). So, just need to take those greater or equal to `0.6`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks simple

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Much less efficient solution than using variables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's why I prefer this way too, like I mentioned under your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To find the 60th percentile in 2016 in MySQL (pre 8):

```
select min(age)
from (select c.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from (select c.*
            from cust c
            where year = 2016
            order by age
           ) c cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) c
where rn >= @rn * 0.6;
```

To find the corresponding ages in 2017, you can `join` this in:

```
select c.* from cust c join
     (select min(age) as age_2016
      from (select c.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
            from (select c.*
                  from cust c
                  where year = 2016
                  order by age
                 ) c cross join
                 (select @rn := 0) params
           ) c
      where rn >= @rn * 0.6
     ) cc
     on c.age >= cc.age_2016 where year = 2017;
```

Comment: I like solutions using variables the way you did, but tje disatvantage is that query looks complicated :)